# How to sync with Github repos?

Tags: git

I have to setup a git server to host about 200 public repos. It is for those servers which cannot access Internet(especially, Github).

Here is how I am doing it:

1. cd /data/githubRepos/bootstrap && git pull
2. cd /data/gitLocalRepos/ && rm -rf bootstrap.git && git clone --bare /data/githubRepos/bootstrap bootstrap.git

and do the same operations for other repos.

Is there some better solutions?

Comment: Do you need the second step at all? Why can't others that need it just clone directly from the repo in #1?

Comment: I want to provide a `git://` service. So across servers can access it.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't just create a proxy to the Internet using the one server that has access, and have others use github directly through that server? You are creating a lot of management problems with this approach.

Comment: I could, just the boss want put all repos(public repos, company repos) into one...

Comment: The git:// service could still access the repo in /data/githubRepos/ just as well as it can access /data/gitLocalRepos/, no?

Comment: I'm not sure, I followed `Git-on-the-Server`, it says should do a `git clone --bare`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create a bare repository (kept in sync with gitHub through periodic git pull) and exported locally through git-daemon to the other working copies.